# Problemas de asignación de valor a la variable de una clase

Tags: python

Podrían explicarme por qué en este código X=2 y Y =2, será que la expersión p2.x = 2 reasigna el valor 2 a X en lugar del 1 de Points(1,2)?

```
class Points(object):

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def print_point(self):
        print('x=',self.x,' y=',self.y)

p2=Points(1,2)

p2.x=2

p2.print_point()
```

Comment: Es correcto, tanto `x` como `y` son atributos de la clase y para acceder a ellos se utiliza la sintaxis con punto `p2.x` accede al atributo `x` de la instancia `p2` de la clase `Points`

Comment: Puedes usar el formato `objeto.atributo` para acceder a cualquier atributo de un objeto dado. Python no sabe nada de privacidad.

Comment: Si quisieras que se inicializara y jamás cambiara tendrías que crear un `getter` para `x` y en el `setter` no hacer nada o devolver un mensaje diciendo que ese atributo no puede ser cambiado después de ser inicializado

Comment: Excelente! Clarísimo! Gracias!!!